# Vector of objects, which each give this, to it's members

Tags: c++

I have two classes, Vertex, and Triangle.  First I create a field of vertices, and then I create a vector of triangle faces out of the vertex field.  Each vertex needs a pointer or reference to each triangular face adjacent to it.

Here is a simplified example of what I have, but it's not working.

```
struct Vertex {
    float x, y, z;
    vector<Triangle*> adj_triangles;
}

struct Triangle {
    Vertex *v1;
    Vertex *v2;
    Vertex *v3;

    Triangle(Vertex *v1_in, Vertex *v2_in, Vertex *v3_in) {
        v1 = v1_in;
        v2 = v2_in;
        v3 = v3_in;
        v1->adj_triangles.push_back(this);
        v2->adj_triangles.push_back(this);
        v3->adj_triangles.push_back(this);
    }
}

struct Mesh {
    vector< vector<Vertex> > field;
    vector< Triangle > triangles;
}
```

And I am populating like this,

```
triangles.push_back( Triangle ( v1, v2, v3 ) );
```

Where of course v1, v2, v3 are valid pointers to Vertex objects.

When I try to access a Triangle from a vertex, like this,

```
v.adj_triangles[index]->member;
```

I do not get what I want.  I think this probably because pushing back a temporary triangle first creates the temporary, initialized it's values according to it's this pointer.  And then it is copied by value and destroyed.  So each vertex has a pointer to an object that no longer exists.

So I was wondering what the be the way to accomplish this?  Should I use vectors of smart pointers?

Thank you for you time.

**EDIT:**

Just wanted to make it more clear what I am asking for.  Is my analysis of why the codes does not work correct?  What do you think of this?

```
struct Triangle {
    Vertex *v1;
    Vertex *v2;
    Vertex *v3;

    Triangle(Vertex *v1_in, Vertex *v2_in, Vertex *v3_in) {
        v1 = v1_in;
        v2 = v2_in;
        v3 = v3_in;
    }
    void give_address() {
        v1->adj_triangles.push_back(this);
        v2->adj_triangles.push_back(this);
        v3->adj_triangles.push_back(this);      
    }
}
```

...

```
triangles.push_back( Triangle ( v1, v2, v3 ) );
triangles.back().give_address();
```

Which solves the problem.  But I am wondering if this is a bad practice.

Comment: How are you creating `v1,v2,v3` objects?

Comment: They are created like `for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j) field.push_back( Vertex (x, y, z) );`

Comment: Well, `Mesh` uses `vector<Vertex>` and `vector<Triangle>` which will create struct copies rather than pointers.

Comment: I do not get what I want.  <== want to tell us what you want vs what you're getting or should we all just guess?

Comment: Yes, Mesh has the originals.  But each Triangle object is essentially made up of pointers to originals vertices owned by Mesh, and vertex, has pointers to the original Triangles owned by Mesh, which surround them.

Comment: @xaxxon.  I wanted clarification or confirmation about why this does not work, and what would be the best alternative.

Comment: @MVTC perhaps I've missed it, but where do you actually say what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `vector` doesn't have enough space when you `push_back` it will resize, invalidating pointers to any values that were in the `vector` previously.

You need to either reserve the correct amount so that a resize doesn't have to happen, or store pointers to values, instead of the values themselves.

If you go the pointer route, you're best storing a `unique_pointer`

Comment: I'm glad I asked.  I did not know this.  While this didn't seam to be cause of the problem I was having, I'm sure that it would have likely given created problems later on.  Had I not asked, I would have implemented my fix, and probably have never known about the lingering issue.  I used unique_ptr.  Thanks.